# How do you test non-live sites before switching DNS?

Tags: apache, dns, server, testing

I have a few websites that I need to move to a new server - how would I test that they work before switching DNS? What URL would I navigate to?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to modify your hosts file to hardcode the domain name to the new IP address temporarily. See this guide for [OS-specific](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file) instructions. Don't forget to remove the entry again after you're done testing.

Alternatively, you could setup a temporary test subdomain for each site on the new server (`test.example.com`), set it up as an alias, and use this to test with. If you're using control panel software (like cpanel), sometimes these can automate this process, giving you a temporary URL to test with instead.