# Visiting website without nameservers

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, shared-hosting, nameserver, migration

### Context

I am migrating a WordPress website from a Plesk server to a cPanel server. Before I change the nameservers to point to the new website, I would like to test that everything is ok (e.g., database, files, etc...).

### Problem

I cannot visit the migrated website if the nameservers are not set. I tried typing the IP directly in my browser, but of course it didn't work, since there are many websites hosted in the same server.

So I guess **my question is**: How can I access the website before the new nameservers are set? Is it even possible?

Comment: See this related question: [How do you test non-live sites before switching DNS?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60549/how-do-you-test-non-live-sites-before-switching-dns)

Answer (score 4):

cPanel can do this by going to the following url: 
`http://[ip-address]/~[cPanel-username]`

Comment: touche. that's an answer.

Comment: This is an [Apache feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/public_html.html), not strictly cPanel. However, this won't work if you are using root-relative URLs.